# subprocess.wait() not waiting for Popen process to finish (when using threads)?

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, popen

I am experiencing some problems when using `subprocess.Popen()` to spawn several instances of the same application from my python script using threads to have them running simultaneously. In each thread I run the application using the `popen()` call, and then I wait for it to finish by calling`wait()`. The problem seems to be that the `wait()`-call does not actually wait for the process to finish. I experimented by using only one thread, and by printing out text messages when the process starts, and when it finishes. So the thread function would look something like this:

```
def worker():
    while True:
        job = q.get() # q is a global Queue of jobs
        print('Starting process %d' % job['id'])
        proc = subprocess.Popen(job['cmd'], shell=True)
        proc.wait()
        print('Finished process %d' % job['id'])
        job.task_done()
```

But even when I only use one thread, it will print out several "Starting process..." messages, before any "Finished process..." message appears. Are there any cases when `wait()` does not actually wait? I have several different external applications (C++ console applications), which in turn will have several instances running simultaneously, and for some of them my code works, but for others it won't. Could there be some issue with the external applications that somehow affects the call to `wait()`?
The code for creating the threads looks something like this:

```
for i in range(1):
    t = Thread(target=worker)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
q.join() # Wait for the queue to empty
```

**Update 1**:
I should also add that for some of the external applications I sometimes get a return code (`proc.returncode`) of -1073471801. For example, one of the external applications will give that return code the first two times `Popen` is called, but not the last two (when I have four jobs).

**Update 2**:
To clear things up, right now I have four jobs in the queue, which are four different test cases. When I run my code, for one of the external applications the first two `Popen`-calls generate the return code -1073471801. But if I print the exact command which `Popen` calls, and run it in a command window, it executes without any problems.

**Solved!**
I managed to solve the issues I was having. I think the problem was my lack of experience in threaded programming. I missed the fact that when I had created my first worker threads, they would keep on living until the python script exits. By mistake I created more worker threads each time I put new items on the queue (I do that in batches for every external program I want to run). So by the time I got to the fourth external application, I had four threads running simultaneously even though I only thought I had one.

Comment: try a ``print proc.wait()`` and check the returncode.

Answer (score 14):

You could also use [`check_call()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) instead of Popen. [`check_call()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) waits for the command to finish, even when `shell=True` and then returns the exit code of the job.

Comment: seems Popen also does not wait when `stdin=ps.stdout`.

Answer (score 13):

Sadly when running your subprocess using `shell=True`, [`wait(`)](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) will only wait for the `sh` subprocess to finish and not for the command `cmd`.

I will suggest if it possible to don't use the `shell=True`, if not possible you can create a process group like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true/4791612#4791612) and use [os.waitpid](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.waitpid) to wait for the process group not just the shell process.

Hope this was helpful :)

Comment: For myself, I've never found a situation where `shell=True` is necessary or useful. It allows you to be lazy and not split a string up if you're getting it from somewhere else, but the lack of need to quote arguments (with different parsing on different platforms) is invaluable - I'd prefer to pass an iterable rather than a string with quoted values which you've got to be careful on the splitting of.

Comment: @Chris: And even the doc advice against using `shell=True` specially when the data to execute come from untrusted source to avoid shell injection.

Comment: there are some cases in which you will get `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` if there if don't use `shell= True`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all  applications your are calling have valid system return codes when they finish

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues as well, but was inspired by yours.

Mine looks like this, and works beautifully:

```
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    startupinfo.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, startupinfo=startupinfo)
    proc.communicate()
    proc.wait()
```

Notice that this one hides the window as well.