# How many kinds of returncode of subprocess.wait()

Tags: python, hadoop, subprocess

I'm so confused about a python-file , which used for copying files from sever to hadoop.

the cmd is: `hadoop fs -put /localhost/* /hadoop/*`
the code is:

```
    cmd = exc_path + ' ' + 'fs -put' + ' ' + src_path + item + ' ' + dst_path
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    code = process.wait()
    logfile.info('type(code) is %s, code is %s\n', type(code), code)
```

For the past several days, it runs ok. But the day before yesterday it returned `code!=0` 
Then yesterday, it ran ok, the `code == 0`, and then today it fails and returned : `type(code) is <type 'int'>, code is 255`

The doc says the `wait()` should return 0 or None, so why do I get a 255? And the cmd 'put' of hadoop should return 0 (when success) and -1 (when fail).

I have found some useful infomation:
    "Sadly when running your subprocess using shell=True, wait() will only wait for the sh subprocess to finish and not for the command cmd."  [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341358/subprocess-wait-not-waiting-for-popen-process-to-finish-when-using-threads)

Answer (score 4):

> The doc says the wait() should return 0 or None, but why I get a 255.

This is wrong. The documentation says:

*Popen.wait()
    Wait for child process to terminate. Set and return returncode attribute.*

And

*Popen.returncode
    The child return code, set by poll() and wait() (and indirectly by communicate()). 
    A  None value indicates that the process hasn’t terminated yet.
    A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (Unix only).*

If the command exits with a non zero exitcode then you will get it.

> And the cmd 'put' of hadoop should return 0(when success) and -1(when fail).

This explanation of why you get  `255` rather `-1` is quite simple and has already be explained  [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726447/why-is-the-exit-code-255-instead-of-1-in-perl).  Basically it is due to Java allowing signed 32 bits values as exit code (-1 for us) but a Posix exit status is an unsigned 8 bits value.

To summarize, a non-zero exit code will tell you that the command failed. If you want to check against a special exit code, special care must be taken when the code is not in the 0-255 range.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Actually, May I know what situation the cmd 'put' of hadoop will return -1 ? 
I have checked that the files is uploads to hadoop from sever, with the same size.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A return code of 255 means the Hadoop process exited with a `-1` return code (*why* that is I don't know).

The reason `wait()` doesn't give you -1 is because negative numbers are reserved for cases when the subprocess exited due to a signal (if it exited due to, say, signal 11, the return code would have been -11).