# python: child dies when parent dies

Tags: python, python-2.7, nohup

I want my python job to start another process and exit, while keeping the child running.

When I start a subprocess using

```
Popen([sys.executable,"foo","bar"])
```

(as [recommended](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-the-os-spawn-family) instead of `spawn`), the child dies when the parent exits (the above `Popen` is about the last thing the parent does).

This, of course, can be remedied using `nohup`:

```
with open("/dev/null","w") as fd:
    Popen(["nohup",sys.executable,"foo","bar"],stdout=fd)
```

(I have to redirect output to `/dev/null` to prevent `nohup` from 
creating file `nohup.out` and announcing that misdeed on `stdout`).

**Is there a *more elegant*/pythonic way to deal with this?**

I also tried `os.fork` + `signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP,signal.SIG_IGN)` and the child still died when the parent exited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [subprocess.wait() not waiting for Popen process to finish (when using threads)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341358/subprocess-wait-not-waiting-for-popen-process-to-finish-when-using-threads)

Comment: How do you produce the situation that "the parent dies" when you test?  Depending on this you might hunt ghosts because something actively kills your child along with the parent, so not the death of the parent is the reason for your child to perish.

Comment: @Alfe: the parent exits on its own, no one does any killing here

Comment: @EminMastizada: my question is almost completely unrelated. No threads, no wait().

Comment: Then you have a strange setup I cannot reproduce.  I start an interactive Python session and type: `from subprocess import Popen`, `p = Popen([ 'bash', '-c', 'while sleep 3; do date; done' ])`, then I exit the session (Ctrl-D).  The child process continues to print dates into my terminal. Or using python in the child: `Popen([ sys.executable, '-c', 'import time\nwhile True:\n  time.sleep(3.0)\n  print time.time()\n' ])`

Comment: Can the termination of th father have any side-effect (e. g. like a closing terminal window, a broken pipe, or similar) which in turn causes the child to terminate?

Comment: @Alfe: you are right: I was testing under emacs where (apparently) parent existing cause tty closure; I tried bash and everything is fine now

Comment: @Alfe: my deployment environment will be cron, I suspect that it will be similar to emacs

Comment: Most dramatic on-topic title on SO?

Comment: @HFBrowning ;-) http://sds.podval.org/zombie.html