# Jython wait() not waiting?

Tags: wait, jython

My Jython wait() is not waiting before executing the next batch file?

```
import subprocess

command = '%s' % (sBatFile)
pipe = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=False, cwd=sBatDir)
out, err = pipe.communicate()
retCode = pipe.wait()

if retCode <> 0:
    return retCode
else:
    return 0
```

I expect the return code to return 0, after the batch file completes.  It's returning 0 but before the batch file completes execution??

Comment: Bit out of my field, but why an if statement, rather than simply return retcode?

Comment: my mistake...no need

Comment: Make sure to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341358/subprocess-wait-not-waiting-for-popen-process-to-finish-when-using-threads if that doesn't work, consider this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4791612/983722